# String concatenation causing timeout

Tags: php, string, timeout, performance, concatenation

Below I have a segment of my code that I recently added to my PHP, which takes an array of integers ($naEUS) and iterates though it, appending the numbers with commas in between with a few exceptions for the start and finish. The end result should be a string that looks like this: ( ### , ### , ### , ### )

```
    $num = count( $naEUS[$f] );
    $resultsFields_values = "(";
    for( $b = 0; $b < $num; $b++ )
    {
        if( $b = 0 )
        {
            $resultsFields_values = substr_replace( $resultsFields_values, " {$naEUS[$b]} " , ( strlen($resultsFields_values) ), 0);
        }
        $resultsFields_values = substr_replace( $resultsFields_values, ", {$naEUS[$b]} " , ( strlen($resultsFields_values) ), 0);
    }
    $resultsFields_values = substr_replace( $resultsFields_values, ")" , ( strlen($resultsFields_values) ), 0);
```

I realize there are plenty of threads addressing string concatenation, but they only address *part* of my problem. I know this is a horribly inefficient way  of doing this. and they show a better way of doing it, but that's easy to find.

What I *really* want to know is **why** it took my 5 second run time PHP to it's 30 second timeout.

Of course, better solutions are also welcome.

Comment: Well... This is embarassing.

if( $b = 0 )...

if( $b == 0 )

Comment: You can edit your post if you like.

Comment: I prefer to leave it as it was, so that someone looking at it can see what happened and follow the conversation. I'm sure it's not hard to deduce but you never know.

I'm not *actually* embarrassed, it's a common mistake.

Comment: Good thinking. And it's a common mistake indeed. I use a couple of languages that do have `=` as a comparison operator, so I do this wrong more often than I'd like. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it depends on the size of the array, but what you're doing here is reallocating that string in every iteration using a rather inefficient function. This will probably work fine as long as your array is small, but when it contains a couple of thousands of items, it's not wonder that execution takes long.

A better solution would be to use the implode function, like this:

```
$resultFields_values = '(' . implode(' , ', $naEUS) . ')';
```

Comment: I looked that up after you mentioned it. My way works, but this is much much much easier.

Comment: While all the answers were helpful, I chose this as the correct one because implode was what I used in the end.

Answer (score 2):

```
for( $b = 0; $b < $num; $b++ )
    if( $b = 0 )
```

With `$b = 0`, you're resetting the loop back to zero on every iteration. `=` is for assignment, `==` is for equality testing.

Comment: Thanks! I know the difference, but it doesn't stop me from doing it every now and then, you know : /

Answer (score 1):

Use comparison operator == instead of $b = 0.

Comment: Haha yeah I figured it out after I posted this. I hate when this happens. I literally looked at this for upwards of an hour.

Comment: By posting you get a more sound relationship to the problem than by staring at it.